# JPA - CriteriaBuilder - Sorting on Integer

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to sort on some Integer field but out of the box the CriteriaBuilder orders my query as Strings:

Example (from small to big):
1 - 10 - 5

How could I solve this? Can I add a comparator or something to the query or?

Code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MessageLog> cq = cb.createQuery(MessageLog.class);
Root<MessageLog> messageLogRoot = cq.from(MessageLog.class);
cq.select(messageLogRoot);

Path<?> path = getPath(sortField, messageLogRoot);
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(path));

 private Path<?> getPath(String sortField, Root<MessageLog> messageLogRoot) {
    Path<?> path;
    if (sortField == null) {
        return messageLogRoot.<Date>get("sendDate");
    }
    switch (sortField) {
        case "messageTypeCode":
            path = messageLogRoot.<Integer>get("messageTypeCode");
            break;
        default:
            path = messageLogRoot.<MessageLogStatus>get("messageLogStatus");
    }
    return path;
}
```

Note: I've got the same problem for dates and my enums. I'm using JPA 2.0

EDIT:

MessageLog entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE_LOG")
public class MessageLog extends Domain {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -2051028296593954613L;

   @Column(name = "SEND_DATE")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @NotNull
   private Date sendDate;

   @Column(name = "MESSAGE_TYPE_CODE")
   @NotNull
   private Integer messageTypeCode;

   @Column(name = "MESSAGE_LOG_STATUS")
   @NotNull
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private MessageLogStatus messageLogStatus;
```

Comment: Can you show your MessageLog entity?

Comment: I assume that you run the code using `"messageTypeCode"` as `sortField` right? What's the actual type in the database? Usually a JPA provider translates `CriteriaQuery.orderBy(...)` to an `order by ...` clause. And if the field in the database is of type `char` or `varchar` or something similar, you'll get the result you got.

Comment: Are you sure getPath is called with the parameter "messageTypeCode" otherwise you fall back to the default case which is an enum mapping to a String (i.e. messageLogStatus). Please debug or enable sql print statement.

Comment: @Frank stupid mistake.. I made a typo in my code. Thanks for pointing at this.. It's solved